# How can I disable workspaces for external monitor?

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors, workspaces

How can I disable workspaces for the external monitor in Maverick Meerkat (10.10)?

Basically, I want to use the ability to switch workspaces, but on the main monitor only, I would like to set a fix window (for example a media player) on the external monitor. Is this possible?

If I cannot do that, is it possible to "pin" windows so they are visible on all workspaces?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some advanced window managers (eg. [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/)) make it possible to assign workspaces to individual screens independently. But if you prefer to stick to Unity and Compiz, just right-click on the top bar of a window and select "Always on Visible Workspace". (You have to unmaximize the window first.)

Comment: In Unity, pressing Alt+Space will give you the same context menu that you see when you right click on the title bar.

Comment: That last comment should be added to the answer, as chrome has another context menu.